# Why golang File struct design like this

Tags: file, go

golang File struct is like this:

```
type File struct{
    *file
}
```

and File struct functiona is also design to recive a pointer,why it design like this?

Comment: @YandryPozo: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is explained in the Go os package source code comments.

For example, this is safe:

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("/tmp/atestfile")
    if err != nil {
        *f = os.File{}
    }
    // finalizer runs
}
```

> Package os
>
> ```
> go/src/os/types.go:
>
> // File represents an open file descriptor.
> type File struct {
>   *file // os specific
> }
>
> go/src/os/file_plan9.go:
>
> // file is the real representation of *File.
> // The extra level of indirection ensures that no clients of os
> // can overwrite this data, which could cause the finalizer
> // to close the wrong file descriptor.
> type file struct {
>   fd      int
>   name    string
>   dirinfo *dirInfo // nil unless directory being read
> }
>
> go/src/os/file_unix.go:
>
> // +build darwin dragonfly freebsd linux nacl netbsd openbsd solaris
>
> // file is the real representation of *File.
> // The extra level of indirection ensures that no clients of os
> // can overwrite this data, which could cause the finalizer
> // to close the wrong file descriptor.
> type file struct {
>   pfd      poll.FD
>   name     string
>   dirinfo  *dirInfo // nil unless directory being read
>   nonblock bool     // whether we set nonblocking mode
> }
>
> go/src/os/file_windows.go:
>
> // file is the real representation of *File.
> // The extra level of indirection ensures that no clients of os
> // can overwrite this data, which could cause the finalizer
> // to close the wrong file descriptor.
> type file struct {
>   pfd     poll.FD
>   name    string
>   dirinfo *dirInfo // nil unless directory being read
> }
> ```